# Como abrir URL en Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, dotnetcore

Tengo la URL file://10.10.10.20/Certificacion/Estrategia%20Comercial/PDF/3016FVE25956.pdf

si la copio en el navegador se abre el archivo

pero cuando la abro desde ANGULAR me aparece el error
Not allowed to load local resource file://10.10.10.20/Certificacion/Estrategia%20Comercial/PDF/3016FVE25956.pdf

```
 this.http.post("https://localhost:44344/api/SeguimientoVTEX/GetUrlDocument",{Documento:factura}).subscribe((data)=>{
  //console.log(data);
  url= data[0];
  
  const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
  tempLink.href = 'file:///'+url
  tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  tempLink.click();
  
},error=>{
  console.log("error ",error);})
```

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de un mecanismo de protección que tienen los navegadores. Fíjate que estás tratando de cargar un recurso local (`file`) en lugar de un recurso remoto por el protocolo HTTP(s) (`http`o `https`).

Esto es para evitar que algún diseño malicioso o que algún sitio web que haya sido comprometido pueda acceder a tus ficheros. Imagina que un atacante es capaz de inyectar código o de ejecutar código en una web conocida (por ejemplo, la [RAE](https://www.rae.es/)). Esto podría hacer que intente abrir un fichero de tu equipo (un fichero con contraseñas o similar).

La diferencia es que cuando tu indicas la URL manualmente, el browser sabe que lo estás haciendo tu, en lugar de la web que tienes cargada, de ahí el motivo que sí te deje abrir ficheros, como un PDF, y visualizarlo con un plugin de PDFs por ejemplo.

Puedes leer un poco más [aquí (en inglés)](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/).

Cualquier duda puedes utilizar los comentarios. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: no me soluciona nada .....

Comment: Correcto, ya que no se puede, es el propio navegador el que te lo está prohibiendo y no lo permite.

Answer (score 0):

No podrías usar

```js
windows.open(url, '_blank');
```

?

Es lo que se hace típicamente, es cierto lo que te dicen arriba, el navegador no puede acceder al sistema de ficheros así no más